# SQLで条件にマッチするレコードが存在するか判定したい

Tags: c#, sql

```
tableA
ID  YMD        DAY     SE    　 CSE  　　　CODE
22  19970901    0       0       0       KG00100
22  19970901    0       1       0       KG00610
22  19970901    0       1       1       KG01042
22  19970901    0       1       2       KG00361
22  19970901    0       1       3       KG00363
22  19970901    0       2       0       KG01150
22  19970901    0       3       0       KG01631
22  19970901    0       3       1       KG01632

22  19970912    0       0       0       KG00200
22  19970912    0       1       0       KG01631
22  19970912    0       1       1       KG01632
22  19970912    0       2       0       KG01670
22  19970912    0       3       0       KG01320
22  19970912    0       3       1       KG01180
22  19970912    0       3       2       KG02281
22  19970912    0       3       3       KG00930

22  19971205    0       0       0       KG00200
22  19971205    0       1       0       KG04830
22  19971205    0       1       1       KG04230
22  19971205    0       1       2       KG04410
22  19971205    0       2       0       KG01633
22  19971205    0       2       1       KG01670
22  19971205    0       2       2       KG00362

22  19971216    0       0       0       KG00200
22  19971216    0       1       0       KG05540
22  19971216    0       1       1       KG06140
22  19971216    0       1       2       KG00510
22  19971216    0       2       0       KG01670

22  19980127    0       1       0       KG01110
22  19980127    0       1       1       KG05160
22  19980127    0       1       2       KG05310
22  19980127    0       1       3       KG05320
22  19980127    0       1       4       Z10180
22  19980127    0       2       0       KG01670
22  19980127    1       0       0       KG00200
22  19980127    1       1       0       KG01633
22  19980127    1       1       1       KG00362

22  19980206    0       0       0       KG00200
22  19980206    0       1       0       KG05040
22  19980206    0       1       1       KG01140
22  19980206    0       2       0       KG01110
22  19980206    0       2       1       KG05160
22  19980206    0       2       2       KG05310
22  19980206    0       2       3       KG05320
22  19980206    0       2       4       Z10180
22  19980206    0       3       0       KG01633
22  19980206    0       3       1       KG01670
22  19980206    0       3       2       KG00362
```

お世話になります。
上記の表で同じ日付(YMD)の中で　DAYのが0　SEが0　CSEが0　でCODEがKG00100もしくはKG00200の値を持っていないIDと日付を抽出したいです。
期待値としては　ID22　19980127のDAY0のグループにはCODE KG00200もしくはKG00100が含まれていないので22　19980127　が抽出できるとうれしいです。
ID  YMD        DAY     SEQ   　 CSEQ 　　　CODE
22  19980127    0       0       0       KG00200
このレコードをインサートしたいと考えています。

DBはmanagement stadioです。

ご教授よろしくお願いします。

追記
各日付の中で　DAYが0　SEが0　CSEが0　　CODEがKG00200もしくはKG00100がない日付とIDを知りたいです。

Comment: DBの「management stadio」とはSQL Server Management Studioのことでしょうか？でしたら「SQL Server 20xx (R2)」のようにバージョンを含めて書かれた方が良いと思います。あと質問内容とC#は無関係では。

Comment: #pgrhoさん C#で開発していたので書いていました。SQL Server 2008 R2をしようしています。

Answer (score 0):

まずテーブルに`DAY`, `SE`, `CSE`の条件を適用し、それから`CODE`の除外条件に該当するグループのレコードを除外するようなクエリーを作成すればよいと思います。
ですので`NOT EXISTS`を使用して

```
WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT *
      FROM tableA
     WHERE DAY = '0'
       AND SE = '0'
       AND CSE = '0'
)
SELECT *
  FROM cte t1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
      FROM cte t2
     WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID
       AND t1.YMD = t2.YMD
       AND t1.DAY = t2.DAY
       AND t2.CODE IN ('KG00100', 'KG00200')
)
```

このようなクエリーで実現できると思います。

## 追記

質問の意図としては`GROUP BY ID, YMD`を掛ける必要があるようですので、上のクエリーに対して

- 2個目の`SELECT *`を`SELECT DISCTINCT ID, YMD`に変更
- `AND t1.DAY = t2.DAY`を削除

すれば意図通りになるのではないかと思います。
ですが出力をグループ化するのであれば初めから

```
SELECT ID, YMD
  FROM tableA
 WHERE DAY = '0'
   AND SE = '0'
   AND CSE = '0'
 GROUP BY ID, YMD
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN CODE LIKE 'KG00[12]00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

のように`HAVING`句を使用して抽出を行うこともできます。

Comment: #pgrhoさん いつも、回答ありがとうございます。教えていただいたSQLを発行したのですが、思い通りの結果が得られませんでした。

Comment: #pgrhoさん　もともとDBの中にはないデータを探して、なければデータを挿入するというやり方を考えているので少し複雑なSQLになるかと思いますが、時間がかかっているのでお力を借りれればと思います。

Comment: #pgrhoさん なかなかうまく行かないです。少し考えてからまた質問させていただきます。